# Build matrix in python for X time of for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, matrix, refactoring

I got issue where I know the len of for loop that I want to preform on but it's multi level.

It mean that it can deep down into 7 levels of for loops , I have the old code for the exists for loop with 7 levels and I want to break it down into lego blocks for improve the expansion of the code.

Can any one help me to convert the current loop to something more elegant ?

```
def create_ref_dict(self):
    idx = 0
    while idx < self.total_size:
        # Todo - add humidity
        # Todo - add support for 2 attenuators
        for temperature in self.temperature_list: # * [10,15,20]
            for angle in self.angle_list: # * [1,2,3]
                for att in self.att_list: # * [4,5,6]
                    for time_profile in self.timing_profile_list:  # * [7,8,9]
                        for energizing_pattern in self.ep_list: # * [15,40,30]
                            for beacon_bo in self.beacon_bo_list: # * [4,9,88]
                                for test_iteration in self.number_of_iterations: # * [1,2]
                                    tmp_dict = {'Oven_Temperature': temperature,
                                                'Tag_Angle': angle,
                                                'User_GW_DCA_Raw': att,
                                                'GW_Timing_List': time_profile,
                                                'Energizing_Pattern_List': energizing_pattern,
                                                'GW_Beacon_BO': beacon_bo,
                                                'Number_of_Test_Iterations': test_iteration}
                                    self.ref_dict[idx] = tmp_dict
                                    idx += 1
```

Comment: [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will help a little: this code creates a list of dictionaries with all the possible combinations of values for each parameter. Each dictionary represents a configuration, and the list of dictionaries is equivalent to the ref_dict dictionary in the original code.

You can access each configuration by its index in the list, instead of iterating over nested loops.

```
def create_ref_dict(self):
    self.ref_dict = [{'Oven_Temperature': temperature,
                      'Tag_Angle': angle,
                      'User_GW_DCA_Raw': att,
                      'GW_Timing_List': time_profile,
                      'Energizing_Pattern_List': energizing_pattern,
                      'GW_Beacon_BO': beacon_bo,
                      'Number_of_Test_Iterations': test_iteration}
                     for temperature in self.temperature_list
                     for angle in self.angle_list
                     for att in self.att_list
                     for time_profile in self.timing_profile_list
                     for energizing_pattern in self.ep_list
                     for beacon_bo in self.beacon_bo_list
                     for test_iteration in self.number_of_iterations]
```